# Is there some routine optimized for performing std::lower_bound on unique sorted integer sequences?

Tags: stl

Does an implementation of std::lower_bound() exist, which is optimized for sorted and unique integer sequences?

Answer (score 1):

`lower_bound` is pretty close to optimal for integer sequences, and ONLY works on sorted sequences. unique doesn't change much really.

The only thing worth optimizing is if your integers have a specific *distribution*, in which case there are slightly more optimal algorithms, but none are implemented in the standard library. I assume this is because the implementations require items where comparisons are integer based, and also have specific distributions, which makes them pretty specific to the data, and thus not a good fit for a standard library.

However, if you have a BILLION items to search through, `lower_bound` still only takes 30 comparisons, so... its not worth further optimization.  I can pretty much guarantee that optimizing this search will not make real programs noticeably faster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's called `binary_search`.  It will return `true` if the element exists in the sequence, and `false` otherwise.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

int main () {
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 };
    assert (!std::binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), 1));
    assert ( std::binary_search(v.begin(), v.end(), 4));
    }
```

[Later]
Ok, I completely misread the question :-(

`lower_bound` works fine on a sorted sequence.
It turns out that the sequence needs only to be partitioned, but a sorted sequence satisfies that criterion.
See [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound).